# Sharepoint Online Can't create DocumentSet with CSOM Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.dll

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, officedev, document-set

I am using the OfficeDev.Core to create DocumentSet "Folder" in sharepoint Online in a Provider Hosted Add-in in C#.

I am using the lastest CSOM C# library for Sharepoint On line :
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll V16.1.5813.1200
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement.dll V16.1.5813.1200

This was working fine for months and yesterday we notice that the method Create from the class  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet.DocumentSet return an error unknown !

I use a AppOnly Access Token with highest permissions.

Do you have any ideas or workarounds to create a documentset with CSOM ?

Thanks

PS: I try to create this documentset with the UI and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, at least i'm experiencing at the moment the same issue (`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError` exception) while trying to create a document set via CSOM API in *SharePoint Online*.

**How to reproduce?**

While creating a document set via [`Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/16.1.5813.1200):

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

var docSetContentType = ctx.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0120D520");
ctx.Load(docSetContentType);

ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var result = DocumentSet.Create(ctx, list.RootFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.Id);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

the exception of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError` occurs in *SharePoint Online*.

> Note: the error has been detected in the latest and previous versions
>   of `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` library. That makes me think it is not 
>   related with CSOM library but rather with SharePoint Online CSOM 
>   service itself.

**Workaround**

But there is a workaround that allows to create a Document Set (without `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet` namespace involved)

```
public static void CreateDocumentSet(List list, string docSetName)
{
        var ctx = list.Context;
        if (!list.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("RootFolder"))
        {
            ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        var itemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        itemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
        itemInfo.LeafName = docSetName;
        itemInfo.FolderUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        var item = list.AddItem(itemInfo);
        item["ContentTypeId"] = "0x0120D520";
        item["HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type"] = "SharePoint.DocumentSet";
        item.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

> Has been verified against SharePoint `2010`, `2013` and `Online` versions

Usage

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
CreateDocumentSet(list,docSetName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution on this post:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199336/creating-document-sets-with-sharepoint-csom-api/199718#199718

I experienced the same issue on my tenant on monday morning 14/11/2016

The creation of the documentset stop working suddenly

The existing code :

```
var devisCT = globalHostWeb.GetContentTypeByName(SPConstants.CTName_Devis);
dsQuoteFolder = rootFolder.CreateDocumentSet(folderName, devisCT.Id);
```

and solution that works for me is :

```
var devisCT = devisLib.GetContentTypeByName(SPConstants.CTName_Devis); 
dsQuoteFolder = rootFolder.CreateDocumentSet(folderName, devisCT.Id);
```

I now take the content type from the Library where I want to create the documentset.

The ContentTypeId retrieved is longuer and this ID works.

You can notice that I use the method GetContentTypeByName and it works as well as the GetContentTypeByID.